# Mysql problems - Mysql fetch array and adding to database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi 
I have two mysql problems

a) I'm confused on why this code won't add data to my database:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Table ('adder', 'username')
VALUES('$myusername','$username1')";
mysql_query( $sql, $con ) or trigger_error( mysql_error( $con ), E_USER_ERROR );
```

here is the full error: "you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Add (`username`, `name`, `number`) VALUES('56', 'Name', 'number')' at line 1"

and before you ask, yes the data is there

b) I'm having problems with mysql_fetch_array

This is the code:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$mysqlusername", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Add WHERE adder=\"$username\"";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($row)) {
echo "$username hasn\'t added anyone";
}
else {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<a href=\"/".$row[username]."><".$row[username]."</a>"; 
}
}
```

The error here is:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in....

And yes the data is there on the database aswell..

Any ideas??

Thanks for the help :)
Niall

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...` You omitted the important part that comes afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

a) You really should have included the complete error, but I'm fairly certain the syntax error is that you are attempting to put the names of columns in single quotes, which is not allowed.  You should instead use backticks (the key to the left of "1" on your keyboard):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Table (`adder`, `username`)
VALUES('$myusername','$username1')";
```

b) Again, *please* include the full error.  That warning occurs when the `mysql_query` function fails, since `$result` is just the value false instead of a MySQL resource.  What is the value of `$username` when you get that error?  It's likely something is causing the query to be invalid.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should have said "INSERT INTO TABLE `Add`(`adder`, `username`)"

and Add should be enclosed in backticks (`) because it could be a reserved word, and you shouldn't name a table like that.